# .sh file cannot be executed without explicitly calling sh

Tags: shell, permissions

Let's say I have a file called `run.sh` that contains:

```
#! /bin/sh -x

x-www-browser index.html
```

And `ls -l run.sh` says:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername myusername 39 Jan  9 19:32 run.sh
```

And `./run.sh` says:

```
bash: ./run.sh: Permission denied
```

Why does it not work? Why does `sh -x run.sh` work perfectly?

---

**More info, since it's not so easy apparently**

If I do a `sudo`, it will not output an error, but won't do anything either.

```
myusername@crunchbang:/mnt/data$ sudo ./run.sh
[sudo] password for myusername: 
myusername@crunchbang:/mnt/data$
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The filesystem `run.sh` is on has been mounted `noexec`.

Comment: This is the file system I'm in, copied from `/etc/fstab`, is it there I should look? `/dev/sda4       /mnt/data       auto    rw,user,auto  0       0`

Comment: No, you should always look at the most accurate view, available via `mount`.

Comment: You're right!!! `mount` command says `/dev/sda4 on /mnt/data type ext4 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)`, but how can it be?

Comment: As described in the `mount(1)` man page, `user` implies `noexec,nosuid,nodev`. You will need to explicitly add `exec` to the mount options to override this.

Comment: It now works after changing `/etc/fstab` and rebooting. Thank you so much, I would never had realized that there were aliases for multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `#!` line has some weird character on it, perhaps an ASCII `Nul` or other non-printing character, a backspace-something maybe.  Some shells have had a problem with MS-DOS/Windows two-byte (carriage-return linefeed) end-of-line markers.  Modern editors can examine files and decide whether they're Unix-style (linefeed) end-of-lines, or Windows style (and maybe even Mac style) text files.  Maybe you've gotten your editor mixed up and written out a Windows text file.

This causes the kernel to not find whatever "executable" is so specified, and it claims that it can't execute the non-existent "executable".

Comment: I tried to investigate what you explained, and rewrote from scratch the file, without copy-pasting, with a linux editor. I also tried to put an empty line at the end of the file. But no luck.

Comment: This usually gives a "bad interpreter" error, not a "permission denied".